# Overloading in python - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, overloading

I'm building a database type object which, when an index is not found, uses an api to retrieve the information, save it to the object/file and return it.

I'd like to do this by overloading the `.loc[x, y]` method of the pandas DataFrame but I can't work out how to do this!

At the moment I have:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('io.hdf.default_format','table')

class DataBase(pd.DataFrame):
    """DataBase Object which can be updated by external api"""
    def __init__(self, path, api=None):
        super(DataBase, self).__init__(pd.read_hdf('store.h5','df'))
        self.api = api
```

I may want to change the `__init__` function to include a `where` argument so I can read only what I need to.

I can't think of a way to overload the `.loc` method properly!

Also, hdf5 is just one method. I'd like to retain the ability to use any other storage methods like sql, or even csv if necessary

Comment: As you can see, loc is not a method but a property, which then in turn has its own get method. So the answer is, it's complicated.

Comment: No, I can't see. I can't find anything useful about `.loc` int the docs or in the core files.

Comment: The way I introspect is simply to use the "?" of the ipython console. In any case it is already in the syntax: a method is thing.do(); but a property/attribute looks like thing.other and anything on the end of that act on the property. `pd.core.indexing._LocationIndexer` and its derivatives have some get methods that act on loc.obj, so you have the find the one that's chosen for your dataframe, subclass it, and overload the getter.

Comment: What do you mean by subclassing?

Comment: I'll try to make a solution for you later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loc` is a property that creates returns a name called `_loc` if its not `None` else it creates a `pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer` on demand. Indexers, by default have access to the DataFrame that created them, so you can modify the DataFrame on a key miss.

You can override the behaviour of `DataFrame.loc` by subclassing `DataFrame` and `_LocIndexer` as thus.

```
class MyLocIndexer(_LocIndexer):    
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:                   
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            item = db.fetch_item(key)
            self[key] = item
            return item
            # `return self[key]' is better as it also works when accessing a 
            # whole axis

class MyDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._loc = MyLocIndexer(self, "loc")
```

The above is written in python3, so you will have to fix the super statements if you are using python2.

Answer (score 1):

Adding years later to the answer above, if you ever end up overloading the basic pandas classes, you can override some constructor properties to ensure that the new class is sustained through the standard pandas manipulations, from the [Internals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html):

- _constructor: Used when a manipulation result has the same dimesions as the original.
- _constructor_sliced: Used when a manipulation result has one lower dimension(s) as the original, such as DataFrame single columns
  slicing.
- _constructor_expanddim: Used when a manipulation result has one higher dimension as the original, such as Series.to_frame() and
  DataFrame.to_panel().

e.g.:

```
@property
def _constructor(self):
    return MyDataFrame
```